# Displaying custom XMP Metadata in Adobe After Effects `Metadata` panel

Tags: extendscript, after-effects, xmp

With some ExtendScript, I'm adding custom XMP Metadata to an Adobe After Effects project file using the excellent code found in [this thread over on the Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1302473).  I have verified that the metadata is being written to my project file as my script can access it between AE sessions.  However, I was hoping that I could inspect see the custom Metadata within AE's native Metadata window panel (Window > Metadata).  Unfortunately, it's not showing up there, nor does it show up in the panel's context menu dialog "Project Metadata Display...".  Is there a way to display custom metadata set by ExtendScript in this panel?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies in your scenario, however this is taken from the Adobe after effects help documentation.

> In After Effects, the Metadata panel (Window > Metadata) shows static
>   metadata only. Project metadata is shown at the top of the panel, and
>   Files metadata is shown at the bottom. Temporal metadata is visible in
>   After Effects only as layer markers.

Source:  https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/xmp-metadata.html#working_with_xmp_metadata_in_after_effects

So I believe according to the documentation your xmp meta data may be shown at the bottom.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks, Felice, I thought that might be the case, too.  But, alas, I didn't find it displayed on the bottom either.